# How can the theory of prolongation of solutions be applied here to ensure $s_2 < 0$ such that $\varphi(s_2) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

A colleague of mine asked me this question but I couldn't answer it. Context: let $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^3, \gamma(s) = (x(s), 0, z(s)), s \in I$ be a plane curve parametrized by arc-length and $\varphi: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\gamma'(s) = (\cos(\varphi(s)), 0, \sin(\varphi(s))) \ \forall s \in I$ and consider the system:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{\prime}(s) &=\cos \varphi(s), \quad z^{\prime}(s)=\sin \varphi(s), \\
\varphi^{\prime}(s)+\frac{\sin \varphi(s)}{x(s)} &=\alpha \frac{\cos \varphi(s)}{z(s)} .
\end{aligned}
$$
with initial conditions $$
x(0)=x_{0} > 0, \quad z(0)=z_{0}>0, \quad \varphi(0)=0
$$
where $\alpha < 0$. The question is the following: why is it that there exists $s_2 < 0$ such that $\varphi(s_2) = \frac{\pi}{2}$? This is a claim the author of the article "Invariant singular minimal surfaces" makes in the proof of a theorem (which I'll attach below to give more context) and he claims it follows by "standard theory on prolongation of solutions", but I haven't been able to see why this is indeed true. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: I think you must have meant that $\;\varphi:I\to\Bbb R\;$ , and not  $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ as codomain, otherwise it doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: The "standard theory of prolongation" is that the maximal solution leaves every compact set in the time-space domain of the ODE system. So construct a suitable box and show that there can not be any singularities that make the solution escape in a space-face...

Comment: @DonAntonio you're right, that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: @LutzLehmann Can you elaborate a bit further? It's still fuzzy to me